# Neo4j: Create a list of items when contain another item

Tags: neo4j, cypher, vsm

I want to create a new list (c2) out of intersection of Buy1 with an Item346
Buy1 : [Item 12, Item 23, Item 7, Item 562, Item 346, Item 85]

List I want to return (vsm representation)
c2 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want 0's for when the values aren't equal, and 1's for when they are, you can use a list extraction using CASE to handle the output:

```
WITH ['Item 12', "Item 23", "Item 7", "Item 562", "Item 346", "Item 85"] as buy1, "Item 346" as item
RETURN [i in buy1 | CASE WHEN i = item THEN 1 ELSE 0 END] as output
```

EDIT: If your input is a list of items, and not just a single item, then we can use a list membership check (using `IN`) to decide when to output 1 or 0:

```
WITH ['Item 12', "Item 23", "Item 7", "Item 562", "Item 346", "Item 85"] as buy1, ["Item 346", "Item 7"] as items
RETURN [i in buy1 | CASE WHEN i IN items THEN 1 ELSE 0 END] as output
```

Comment: if I Item was a list too?What can we do then?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the intersection of two lists? Or how to make this work if the items in the list were lists themselves, instead of strings?

Comment: in the given example:

(c2) out of intersection of Buy1 with a list cmany= [Item346, Item7]
 Buy1 : [Item 12, Item 23, Item 7, Item 562, Item 346, Item 85]

List I want to return (vsm representation) c2 : [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

Comment: Got it. Updated my answer to cover that case.